# Autocomplete JQuery Ui PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, jquery-ui, pdo, jquery-ui-autocomplete

i try to make autocomplete with jquery ui and pdo connection on php but i can't get the result and not see anything.

Here the Codes

HTML :

```
        <?php 
        require_once "../elements/header.php"; 
        require_once "pemilihadd.php";
        ?>
        <!-- page content -->
        <div class="right_col" role="main">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="x_panel">
                        <div class="x_title">
                            <h2>SISWA <small> Tambah Pemilih</small></h2>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="x_content">
                            <br />
                            <form class="form-horizontal form-label-left input_mask">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-md-1" style="margin-right:5%"></div>
                                    <label class="control-label col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12" for="date-picker_1">NIS</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback">
                                        <input type="text" name="StudentId" class="form-control has-feedback-left" id="StudentId" placeholder="type here ...">
                                        <span class="fa fa-user form-control-feedback left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="ln_solid"></div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-md-3" style="margin-right:4%"></div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-4">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Cancel</button>
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Submit</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
         $(function() {
            $( "#StudentId" ).autocomplete({
              source: "pemilihadd.php"
          });
        });
     </script>
     <!-- /page content -->
     <?php require_once "../elements/footer.php"; ?>
```

Java Script :

```
$(function() {
  $( "#StudentId" ).autocomplete({
    source: "pemilihadd.php"
  });
});
```

And the PHP code :

```
error_reporting(E_ALL*(E_NOTICE | E_WARNING));  

require_once '../../config/database.php';

if (isset($_GET['term'])){
    $return_arr = array();
    try {
        $ac_term = "%".$_GET['term']."%";
        $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT StudentId FROM students WHERE StudentId LIKE :term');
        $stmt->bindValue(":term", $ac_term);
        $stmt->execute();

        while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
          $row_array[] = $row['StudentId'];

          array_push($return_arr, $row_array);
        }
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }

    echo json_encode($return_arr);
}
```

Connection database :

```
error_reporting(E_ALL*(E_NOTICE | E_WARNING));
$dsn= 'mysql:host=localhost; dbname=simvosmp; charset=utf8';
$db_user = 'root';
$db_pass = '';
$db = new PDO($dsn, $db_user, $db_pass, $opt);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to S.O. Are you getting some error? Check your browser's console and the network activity to identify that. Edit your question to add more details about that, please. You may refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to improve your chances of getting an answer.

Comment: that's the full code